# Windows phone - Tap image is not working?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm using Panorama Control, and have image on the top. My XAML code as follow:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/Images/khuyenmai.png" Height="85" Width="85" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="imgKhuyenMai" Tap="imgKhuyenMai_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="305,5,41,0" RenderTransformOrigin="2.205,-6.523"></Image>
    <phone:Panorama  Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

My problem is : "Tap" event is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

In Grid, when Canvas.ZIndex of items is equal, the latter item will cover the ahead item. For example, in your code, Panorama will cover Image item, So you can't Tap it. There are 2 solutions, you can choose one:

set `Canvas.ZIndex = 1` on Image

OR

change sort of your code like this, put Image latter than Panorama:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama/>
    <Image/>
</Grid>
```